# "Lights off" effect of the main application window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

How to make a "**Lights off**" effect for the main application window? I mean this:

- lights on:

[image: https://i114.fastpic.ru/big/2021/0403/82/99d762a64f41236fa710f4969fd07f82.jpg]

- lights off:

[image]

**UPDATE-1:**
I made my own "lights-off" window implementation.

The algorithm is as follows:

1. Create a new hidden child window (darkened window)
2. Creating a screenshot of the main window
3. Fill the darkened window with black brush and copy onto it HDC the screenshot using `AlphaBlend()` function with a certain transparency value
4. Show the darkened window.

And it works great. But there is one drawback - when show and hide the darkened window then all child controls of the main window are painted in its color (darkened window color) for a short time:

[image]

This:

[image]

Here is description from .rc-file:

```
mainWindow DIALOGEX 0, 0, 309, 177
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_CENTER | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,198,156,50,14,WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,252,156,50,14,WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
    CONTROL         "",IDC_TAB1,"SysTabControl32",0x0,7,4,204,111,WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
    PUSHBUTTON      "Button1",IDC_BUTTON1,228,18,22,17,WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
    PUSHBUTTON      "Button2",IDC_BUTTON2,262,43,32,19,WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT1,216,46,35,15,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
    LTEXT           "Static",IDC_STATIC1,223,86,59,11,WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
    LTEXT           "Static",IDC_STATIC2,7,119,36,13,WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
    CONTROL         "Check1",IDC_CHECK1,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_TABSTOP,45,121,56,8
    CONTROL         "Check2",IDC_CHECK2,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_TABSTOP,110,119,36,13
    CONTROL         "Check3",IDC_CHECK3,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_TABSTOP,127,137,44,11
    PUSHBUTTON      "Button3",IDC_BUTTON3,110,154,55,16,WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT2,232,72,40,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
    CONTROL         "",IDC_SLIDER1,"msctls_trackbar32",TBS_BOTH | TBS_NOTICKS | WS_TABSTOP | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,220,106,69,15
    CONTROL         "Radio1",IDC_RADIO1,"Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,21,136,38,10
    CONTROL         "",IDC_SPIN1,"msctls_updown32",UDS_ARROWKEYS|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,100,137,11,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Button4",IDC_BUTTON4,17,149,50,14,WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
    CONTROL         "Check4",IDC_CHECK4,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,203,131,35,11
END
```

**And now question is - how to fix this?**

Comment: Create another window with a black background and an alpha translucency, then position it over your main window.

Comment: Put pointers to all widgets into a container.  Iterate through the container, telling each widget to hide.  The screen will display the window background color, not black.  I'm doing this now in my GUI application (hiding features that require unlocking).

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks for your answer! What styles should the second window have? Should it be a child window? It is important that the second window should responds to the minimazing, maximizing and moving of the main program window.

Comment: Since Windows 8, `WS_EX_LAYERED` is [available for child controls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42569348/7571258). So you could create a black translucent child window that is positioned in z-order above the other controls.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I have updated my question. Can you comment? Thanks!

Comment: @Ig_M you don't need to screenshot the main window at all if the darkened window is translucent. But regarding the drawing issue, after hiding the darkened window, did you try triggering the man window to repaint itself, such as via `InvalidateRect()`+`UpdateWindow()`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, no, I just use `ShowWindow (darkened_wnd_hwnd, SW_HIDE)` and don't send to the parent window any redraw commands...

Comment: @Ig_M Sounds like you need to do so in this situation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I try to use `ShowWindow(darkened_wnd_hwnd, SW_HIDE);
InvalidateRect(ParentHwnd, NULL, true);
UpdateWindow(ParentHwnd)` But it don't help... What can be done?

Comment: It seems that after hiding the darkened window, all child controls do not have time to redraw. Does anyone else have any ideas how to fix this? It looks like a Windows bug.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote for you the first approach mentioned by [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66926187/lights-off-effect-of-the-main-application-window#comment118302709_66926187):

**LightLayer.h**

```
#pragma once    
#include <Windows.h>

class LightLayer
{
public:
    /**
    *  darkness [0-255]
    *   0: light
    * 255: dark
    */
    LightLayer(HWND attachedWindow, int darkness = 180);

    bool isValid() const;

    void turnLightOn();
    void turnLightOff();    

    void setDarkness(int darkness);

    void onWindowPosChanged(LPARAM lParam); 
    void onShowWindow(WPARAM wParam);

private:
    bool mValid;
    bool mMustShow;
    bool mWinPosChanged;

    HWND mLayer;
    HWND mAttachedWin;

    WNDPROC mDefProc;

    void setVisibility(bool visibility);
    void updatePos();
    
    static INT_PTR CALLBACK LightsLayerProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};
```

**LightLayer.cpp**

```
#include "LightLayer.h"

LightLayer::LightLayer(HWND attachedWindow, int darkness)
{    
    mValid = false;
    mMustShow = false;
    mWinPosChanged = false;
    mAttachedWin = NULL;

    mLayer = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_LAYERED,
        L"STATIC", 
        NULL, 
        WS_POPUP, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 
        attachedWindow,
        NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (mLayer)
    {
        mValid = true;
        mAttachedWin = attachedWindow;

        SetWindowLongPtr(mLayer, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR) this);

        mDefProc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLongPtr(mLayer, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR) LightsLayerProc);        

        setDarkness(darkness);
    }            
}

bool LightLayer::isValid() const
{
    return mValid;
}   

void LightLayer::turnLightOn()
{
    setVisibility(false);
}

void LightLayer::turnLightOff()
{
    setVisibility(true);
}    

void LightLayer::setDarkness(int darkness)
{
    if(mValid)
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(mLayer, 0, darkness, LWA_ALPHA);
}

void LightLayer::setVisibility(bool visibility)
{
    if (!mValid)
        return;

    mMustShow = visibility;

    if (visibility) 
        updatePos();
    
    ShowWindow(mLayer, visibility ? SW_SHOW : SW_HIDE);   
    SetFocus(mAttachedWin);
}

void LightLayer::updatePos()
{    
    if (!mValid)
        return;

    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(mAttachedWin, &rc);
    MapWindowPoints(mAttachedWin, GetParent(mAttachedWin), (LPPOINT)&rc, 2);

    SetWindowPos(mLayer, HWND_NOTOPMOST,
        rc.left,
        rc.top,
        rc.right - rc.left,
        rc.bottom - rc.top,
        0);

    OutputDebugStringA("\nupdatePos");
}

void LightLayer::onWindowPosChanged(LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (!mValid)
        return;

    if (mMustShow)
    {        
        updatePos();
        mWinPosChanged = false;
    }
    else
        mWinPosChanged = true;
}

void LightLayer::onShowWindow(WPARAM wParam)
{
    setVisibility(wParam && mMustShow);
}


INT_PTR CALLBACK LightLayer::LightsLayerProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LightLayer* caller = reinterpret_cast<LightLayer*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));

    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_BACKGROUND));
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    }

    return caller->mDefProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And now add this to your dialog procedure:

```
LightLayer* lightLyr = nullptr;

INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {            
        lightLyr = new LightLayer(hDlg, 180);
        
        // Check if it's valid (e.g. no errors upon window creation)
        if (! lightLyr->isValid())
        {
            delete lightLyr;
            lightLyr = nullptr;
        }    
    }
    break;  
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {

        case IDC_OFF:
        {
            if(lightLyr)
            {
                lightLyr->turnLightOff();
                SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_ON, BM_SETCHECK, BST_UNCHECKED, 0);    
            }
            break;
        }

        case IDC_ON:
        {
            if(lightLyr) 
            {
                lightLyr->turnLightOn();
                SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_OFF, BM_SETCHECK, BST_UNCHECKED, 0);  
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
                        
    case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED:
        if(lightLyr)
            lightLyr->onWindowPosChanged(lParam);
        break;

    case WM_SHOWWINDOW:
        if(lightLyr)
            lightLyr->onShowWindow(wParam);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        delete lightLyr;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here's a [showcase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykyVg.jpg).

Comment: Consider also handling `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`, `WM_SIZING`/`WM_SIZE`, etc. Also, you should use `SetWindowSubclass()` instead of `SetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_WNDPROC)`. And consider having `LightLayer` subclass the `attachedWindow` so the main window does not have to forward messages to `LightLayer`

Comment: @GZPERRA, thanks a lot for this code! But I see some flaws here. For example, when the main window is moved, the main window loses focus. And here is another one - after minimizing and restoring the main window, the main window and "shaded" window "flies out" not synchronously. And also if you add some controls to "shaded" window they will also have translucency. Unfortunately this implementation doesn't work for me.

Comment: But I think a more appropriate implementation is to create a child window, then make a screenshot of the main window, shade it and to draw it on child window. Now controls can be placed on top. It is clear that this will be a fake shading, but it suits me. I am currently implementing this algorithm.